# Storage and Serialization in AS3 / Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, blackberry-playbook

Thought Id ask here before jumping into a problem on the **Blackberry Playbook (Adobe Flex)**

I have a search form and a SearchCriteria class representing the search form's input, for example:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    private var firstname:String;
    private var surname:String;

    public function SearchCriteria()
    {}

    public function getFirst():String{
           return firstname;
    }
    ...
```

As the person fills out the form, I would like to cache a copy in memory of the SearchCriteria so that if there is a problem, or the user turns off their tablet, I could recreate the form when they log back in.

**TL;dr version:** Basically, what is the *best way* to Serialize and Deserialize objects in Actionscript 3? (particularly on the Blackberry Playbook)

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking specifically about serialization and deserialization I'd recommend **AMF3** format.

It is used by [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) mentioned by Timofei Davydik. You can also serialize objects with [ByteArray.writeObject()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeObject%28%29) and then save the ByteArray to a file.

Note that if you want to use strongly typed object (recommended) you should annotate your model classes with [[RemoteClass]](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html) metadata. If you don't want some properties to be serialized use [[Transient]](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html) metadata.

Answer (score 2):

You could serialize them to JSON format using the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) library.

And then use SharedObject or [SQLite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html) (works well in Playbook).